# Event Listener Called on Every Module Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

Hi I have a event Listener in symfony2, That I have registered accordingly as well, it need to call at before of any function call of any controller in my module. But it is calling on Whole application, I mean every module. but I want it to called only when some one will open My Module only.

```
//My Event Listener
namespace Edu\AccountBundle\EventListener;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Edu\AccountBundle\CommonFunctions\CommonFunctions;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Edu\AccountBundle\Controller\FinancialYearController;

/*
 * Class:BeforeControllerListener
 * @DESC:its a Listener which will execute at very first of any action     of any  controller in Account module (Act as a beforeFilter Symfony2)
 * @param : @session,@route,@db
 * @sunilrawat@indivar.com
 * @09-07-2015
 */

class BeforeControllerListener
{

private $session;
private $router;
private $commonFunctions;

public function __construct(Session $session, Router $router, DocumentManager $dm)
{
    $this->session = $session;
    $this->router = $router;
    $this->dm = $dm;
    $this->commonFunctions = new CommonFunctions();
}
public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
{
    $controller = $event->getController();
    if (!is_array($controller)) {
        return;
    }
    if (!$controller[0] instanceof FinancialYearController) {
        if ($this->commonFunctions->checkFinancialYear($this->dm) !== 0 ) {
            return;
        }
        $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'OOPS!, YOU MUST CREATE FINANCIAL YEAR TO MAKE ANY PROCESS IN ACCOUNTS!');
        $redirectUrl= $this->router->generate('financialyear');
        $event->setController(function() use ($redirectUrl) {
            return new RedirectResponse($redirectUrl);
        });
    }
}
}
//Services.xml
<service id="edu.account.listener" class="Edu\AccountBundle\EventListener\BeforeControllerListener">
        <argument type="service" id="session"/>
        <argument type="service" id="router"/>
        <argument type="service" id="doctrine_mongodb.odm.document_manager"/>
            <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="kernel.controller" method="onKernelController"/>
    </service>
```

Now when the Method is calling corectly very begining of any action of any controller, but it is calling for every controller of whole project, Instead I want it to call only in My Particular Module in my application.

Please guide what is missing in this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code check if your controller is not an instance of Finacial Year, shouldn't it be the opposite? `if ( $controller[0] instanceof FinancialYearController) {`

Comment: I have tried it but not working, still calling for every controller for all mudules.

Comment: So Now I am thinking to fix the routes of my modules, and chek them in above function, I could not get any better way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite normal that a `kernel.controller` event listener is called for **every** controller, it's the check inside the event listener that matters and that allows you for an early return if the controller does not match.

Your check does seem wrong though. You probably want to return if the controller is not the class you expect:

```
public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
{
    $controller = $event->getController();

    if (!is_array($controller)) {
        return;
    }

    if (!$controller[0] instanceof FinancialYearController) {
        return;
    }

    if ($this->commonFunctions->checkFinancialYear($this->dm) !== 0 ) {
        return;
    }

    $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'OOPS!, YOU MUST CREATE FINANCIAL YEAR TO MAKE ANY PROCESS IN ACCOUNTS!');
    $redirectUrl= $this->router->generate('financialyear');
    $event->setController(function() use ($redirectUrl) {
        return new RedirectResponse($redirectUrl);
    });
}
```

}

Comment: above code which I posted. as you said that there are wrong check

Comment: As I said, you probably mean to return early when the controller is not the specific controller you are aiming for.

Comment: What exactly you want to explain.

Comment: Is there anything specific about my code above you don't understand?

Comment: What did you change in my code. Sorry I did not see any changes with the code which I have posted. Please make me correct if I am wrong

Comment: The major change is that I return when the controller is not the FinancialYearController, you were doing the opposite.

Comment: But now its not working any more. as it was working before

Comment: I'm sorry @SunilSinghRawat, but can you be clearer on what is not working?

Comment: $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'OOPS!, YOU MUST CREATE FINANCIAL YEAR TO MAKE ANY PROCESS IN ACCOUNTS!');
    $redirectUrl= $this->router->generate('financialyear');
    $event->setController(function() use ($redirectUrl) {
        return new RedirectResponse($redirectUrl);
    }); this one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116352/discussion-between-gerry-and-sunil-singh-rawat).